# How to load native library(.so) in Apache SOLR Cloud mode?

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene

I have written a SOLR custom query parser (implementation of org.apache.solr.search.QParser). My query parser uses some third-party jars. One of the third-party jar requires a native library(.so file) to work. This plugin is working fine when running solr in non-cloud mode, but when I run it on cloud mode, SOLR throws these errors:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /opt/solr-6.2.0/lib/xyz.so already loaded in another classloader
```

I have kept all my third-party and query parser jars and .so file in SOLR_HOME/lib directory and have modified:

1. Added lib dir= "${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/lib/" to solrconfig.xml
2. In SOLR_HOME/bin/solr file:

   SOLR_START_OPTS= "-Djava.library.path=$SOLR_TIP/lib/"

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution for this(credit goes to my one of my senior). When running in cloud mode, follow these instructions:

1. Create `lib` directory inside `SOLR_HOME` and put native-library(.so) file there.
2. In `SOLR_HOME/bin/solr` file, add this line to `SOLR_START_OPTS`:

   SOLR_START_OPTS= "-Djava.library.path=$SOLR_TIP/lib/"
3. Create `lib` folders in each node library (i.e SOLR_HOME/example/cloud/node1/lib, SOLR_HOME/example/cloud/node2/lib) and put all your custom plugin jars into these newly created lib folders.
4. Restart the solr in cloud mode.

Hope, it will help !

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with with this problem as well and found another solution which does not need to touch the starting options.

I just added `<str name="sharedLib">${solr.install.dir}/contrib/my_lib,${solr.install.dir}/dist</str>` to the `solr.xml` ([doc](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_3/format-of-solr-xml.html#solr-xml-parameters)), which then loaded my library on startup so it is shared for all cores.